# Find every occurrence of a regex in a file

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

How can I list every occurrence of a regex in a file, where one line can contain the regex multiple times?

```
Example:
XXXXXXXXXX FOO3 XXXX FOO4 XXX
XXX FOO2 XXXX FOO9 XXXXXX FOO5

The result should be:
FOO3
FOO4
FOO2
FOO9
FOO5
```

The regex would be /FOO./ in this case.

Grep will return every line that matches at least one time. But that's not what I want.

Comment: please include the grep command that you tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the -o option: ([grep man page](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm))

> -o, --only-matching   Show only the part of a matching line that matches
>   PATTERN.

Comment: -o, --only-matching - Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Answer (score 5):

You question is not completely clear, especially since the example data is super generic. But, here are some patterns that might match:

Your pattern matches FOO followed by any character which would match everything to the end of the line. I don't think you want that so try something like this:

`/FOO[0-9]+/` - matches FOO followed by one or more numbers.

`/FOO[^ ]+/` - matches FOO followed by any character that is NOT a space. This might be the best solution given your example pattern.

`/FOO[0-9a-zA-Z]+/` - matches FOO followed by any alphanumeric character

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep -o FOO.` (`-o`: show only matching)

Your regex could even be extended to only match FOO followed by a number, instead of any character (`.` will match whitespace too!):

```
<yourfile grep -o 'FOO[0-9]'
```

Comment: I rolled back the edit, because it broke the redirection. `<yourfile` opens `./yourfile` on file descriptor 0 (stdin). `<yourfile>` breaks the command. It will instruct the shell to write to a file named `./grep` and run the command `-o` (which does not exist).